# Android Paging Library - PositionalDataSource issue

Tags: android, android-paging, android-paging-library

I can get a total number of records from the server, so I am using `PositionalDataSource` for Network call. Everything works well but one problem: even if I don't scroll, the paging library continues fetching all the data from the server. How to solve this problem?
Using: `androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:2.1.1`

Example:

```
override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams, callback: LoadInitialCallback<Doctor>) {
    fetchDataFromApi(params.requestedStartPosition, params.pageSize) { list, totalCount ->
        callback.onResult(list, 0, totalCount)
    }
}
override fun loadRange(params: LoadRangeParams, callback: LoadRangeCallback<Doctor>) {
    fetchDataFromApi(params.startPosition, params.loadSize) { list, totalCount ->
        callback.onResult(list)
    }
}

PagedList.Config.Builder()
        .setPageSize(14)
        .setPrefetchDistance(4)
        .setInitialLoadSizeHint(14)
        .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
        .build()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a similar issue I spend the last two days looking into. For me it turned out, that I had wrapped my `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView`.
However, the pagination library doesn't have built-in support for that according to this [issue on Google tracker](http://issue%7Chttps://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72614329).

> when you put recyclerview inside an infinite scrolling parent, it will layout all of its children because the parent provides infinite dimensions.

Basically the `NestedScrollView` continues triggering fetching more data as if the screen is as long as the complete list

Two options if this is the case for your case too:

1. Change your layout setup to not need the `NestedScrollView`
2. Here is a [code example gist](https://gist.github.com/danaimset/abacaa50d746a4537686a08ecc33c1a9) that helped me create a custom [SmartNestedScrollView]. Note that you have to set `android:fillViewport="true"` as well on this custom container and update the `RecyclerView` to have a height of `wrap_content` and remove the `nestedScrollingEnabled` flag from it.